# Modul system of Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

could any one help me for generating App in Java Swing with the help of different moduls systemof Netbeans 7.0.1's feature ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the NetBeans platform tutorials:

http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/platform.html